# undefined symbol in data segment of assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Putting the statement `data byte 1h` in the assembly program builds fine. But when I replace
the same with `data byte AAh` it throws an error

`undefined symbol : AAh`
What could be the reason for that AA is a valid hexadecimal character and AA is one byte long
So why it marks as undefined

Comment: Numbers must begin with a digit, even if they are hex otherwise the assembler will mistake them for a symbol. Use `0AAh`.

Comment: Thanks that works. I have one more simple addition to it. `fib  dword 01030205h` Now I want to print 5,2,3,1 for this i used this to print 5 : `mov al, byte ptr fib` but for printing all the 4 values I have to loop so I did `mov al, byte ptr [fib+4-cl]`  this threw an error `invalid use of register` How do i access the other bytes in the fib data inside a loop. Here cl is the loop counter

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question.  (When you do, please include the [tag:x86] tag, as well as one for whatever assembler you are using: MASM? NASM? etc).

Comment: Consult a manual about available addressing forms in your operating mode. `cl` is not allowed in any mode.